# Error using Lookup() in a Dataset expression

Tags: reporting-services

**Situation:**

We have multiple databases that users can pull data from and combine into a single report.  Certain databases are grouped together like so.

- Group 1

  - Database1
  - Database2
  - Database3
- Group 2

  - Database4
  - Database5
  - Database6

The groupings are stored in a Dataset (dbsets) that contains 3 columns

- Name
- Databases
- Description

A parameter is used to allow users to select the group they want to report on. The `Available Values` for the parameter is set to `Get values from a query` which points to the dataset above and the `Value field` is set to `Databases` and the `Label field` is set to `Name`. This causes issues when we change the `Databases` values in the dataset since these values are tied to subscriptions, and these values change often.

The Dataset for the report uses an expression to build a dynamic union query like so:

```
= " DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) "
+ " SELECT @sql = COALESCE(@sql + N' UNION ALL ', N'') + N'SELECT * FROM ' + dbname + '.dbo.users u ' "
+ " FROM (VALUES "
+ Parameters!DBGroup.Value
+ " ) t (dbname) "
+ " exec sp_executesql @sql "
```

This builds a query like `select * from Database1.dbo.users union all select * from Database2.dbo.users union all select * from Database3.dbo.users` if the user selects `Group 1` as the parameter value.

If we modify the dataset and add `Database7` to `Group1`, any subscription created with a `Name = Group1` breaks because the underlying value `Databases` has changed

**Attempted Solution:**

To try and fix the subscriptions breaking when the `Value` changes in the dataset, we've tried to change the parameter value to the static `Name` column and use `Lookup()` in the dynamic expression like so:

```
= " DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) "
+ " SELECT @sql = COALESCE(@sql + N' UNION ALL ', N'') + N'SELECT * FROM ' + dbname + '.dbo.users u ' "
+ " FROM (VALUES "
+ Lookup(Parameters!DBGroup.Value, Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Databases.Value, "dbsets")
+ " ) t (dbname) "
+ " exec sp_executesql @sql "
```

This of course throws the error when you try to run the report

> The expression used for the parameter in the dataset refers to a
>   field. Fields cannot be used in query parameter expressions.

**Question:**

Is there any way to retrieve a value from a different dataset inside a dataset expression? Or another solution to this problem inside the report that doesnt include making changes outside of SSRS (ex. changing to stored procedures)

Comment: You mention 1 parameter and 2(?) datasets, but it seems like there's more to it than this. I'm also curious if the parameters allow multiple values and if they have default values set. I don't see why the subscriptions would break if you're selecting all the databases in a group by default. Yes, you can use a dataset to populate parameter values which you can use within subsequent datasets, but I'm not sure if that directly helps you here without more information.

Comment: @StevenWhite  It's one paramater.. single value.. that points to a shared dataset... A different dataset uses the value from the parameter to build a dynamic query expression.... the parameter value looks like `('Database1'),('Database2'),('Database3')`

Comment: The reason the subscriptions fail doing it this way, is because when I alter the dataset and add an extra database, the value becomes `('Database1'),('Database2'),('Database3'),('Database4')`, but the saved value in the `ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions` table is `('Database1'),('Database2'),('Database3')` definitely wasnt a good design

Comment: If i convert to a multi value param, then i'd still have to open every subscription and add the extra values instead of just altering a single dataset.. This is where the `Lookup()` would be beneficial to store a single static value (id) and show the description to user (name) and pull the databases string from the dataset when the report runs

Comment: Rather than hard coding parameter values in the subscription, have you tried letting it use the Default Value. The default should select all databases in a group. Or another approach would be to use a data-driven subscription to lookup the database values dynamically and populate the report parameter that way.

Comment: Just to clarify, `('Database1'),('Database2'),('Database3')` shouldn't be a single parameter value. Group and Database could be separate parameters. Group is visible, database is hidden. When you select a group, database gets the appropriate multiple values by default. Does that make sense?

Comment: @StevenWhite I tried that and could not get it work.. The second parameter logic is throwing me off... For `Available Values` do i choose `Specify values` and use `Lookup()` to get the value from the `dbsets` dataset based on the `Groups` parameter? And what to set for Default?  I know i'm probably missing something simple.

Comment: So I ended up having to create a new dataset that referenced the same `dbsets` shared dataset, but filtered it based on the `DBGroup` parameter.. then added a new hidden parameter that pointed to the new dataset, and set the default value to the same new dataset result.. Now, when i choose a `DBGroup` from the dropdown, it filters the new dataset and sets the new parameter value to the single record that is returned, and i changed my dynamic expression to use the new parameter.value.

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track.